# QString pass by reference issue

Tags: c++, string, qt, parameter-passing, qstring

I have code that supports both native C++ types as well as Qt types.  For example there are `string`'s and `QString`'s which are "equivalent."

I have 2 functions, one that takes `string`'s and one that takes `QString`'s.  The `QString` version converts the parameters to `string`'s and then calls the `string` version of the function.

Here is some generic code of the problem:

```
int myClass::LoadQString(const QString &tagName, QString &toReturn)
{
    string tag = tagName.toStdString();
    string ret = toReturn.toStdString();
    //string& ret = toReturn.toStdString();    //This gives me an error

    return LoadString(tag, ret);
}

int myClass::LoadString(const string& tagName, string& toReturn)
{
    toReturn = "hello world!";

    ...
}
```

So, this code will compile and run...however, when I call `LoadQString()` the second parameter is an empty `QString` once it returns.  You can see in my commented line where I tried `string& ret = ...` to get the reference to work.  If I call `LoadString()` and then check the value of `toReturn` when it returns, it will be "hello world!" as expected.

Just trying to get the `LoadQString()` to work properly.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert from `std::string` back to `QString` after `std::string` version call

```
int myClass::LoadQString(const QString &tagName, QString &toReturn)
{
    string tag = tagName.toStdString();
    string ret = toReturn.toStdString();
    int retCode = LoadString(tag, ret);
    toReturn = QString::fromStdString(ret);
    return retCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `LoadString`, not `LoadXMLAttribute`, and then assign `ret` to `toReturn` after you've called it, then return the `int` that `LoadString` returned.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code...I was copying and pasting from the actual and forgot to changge something

Comment: @user869525 you still need to assign `ret` to `toReturn` to propogate `ret` to the caller of `LoadQString`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, toStdString creates an std::string object as a temporary. So naturally you cannot get a reference out of it, you must store the result in a value or extend its lifetime through a const reference.

However, for what you are doing, assuming `toReturn` is strictly an output parameter and that LoadString performs the actual work:

```
int myClass::LoadQString(const QString &tagName, QString &toReturn)
{
    string tag = tagName.toStdString();
    string ret;
    int result = LoadXMLAttribute(tag, ret);
    toReturn = QString::fromStdString(ret);
    return result;
}
```

If `toReturn` is not strictly an output parameter but also an input one (I recommend you avoid this as it's a rather confusing design practice):

```
int myClass::LoadQString(const QString &tagName, QString &toReturn)
{
    string tag = tagName.toStdString();
    string ret = toReturn.toStdString();
    int result = LoadXMLAttribute(tag, ret);
    toReturn = QString::fromStdString(ret);
    return result;
}
```

Pretty simple. Convert from QString to std::string, call your function which accepts std::strings, store return value, and convert the output parameter (ret) back to a QString assigned to your output parameter (toReturn).

Comment: It's strictly an input param.  Thank you, someone else had this same idea and it worked!  Much appreciated!